# STG_E_WRITEFAULT while reading Excel file with Epplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

In an ASP.NET MVC Core (.netcore2) application, I'm using the following method to read an Excel file.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Import (IFormFile importFile)
{
    using (var excel = new ExcelPackage(importFile.OpenReadStream())
    {
        var sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
        if (sheet == null) return BadRequest("No worksheet.");

        var events = /* import logic */ 
        return Json(events);
    }
}
```

However, epplus is throwing this exception:

> COMException: A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

I've used methods like this in the past to import Excel files, and I don't know what's going wrong.

I've checked:

- Versions of references on the project
- Excel file validity (I'm positive it's a valid xlsx file, not an old xls or other format)

Answer (score 1):

Epplus currently has an issue when targeting `.NetStandard` with text encoding. To resolve this, add this reference to your project.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages" Version="4.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, call this once in your application's startup -

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

[More detail here](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/31) on why this is happening.